# Crontab for starting no-IP does not work

Tags: cron, webserver, dynamic-dns

I have problems with my webserver. Normally you start the No-IP-DUC via `sudo noip2`. I tried to automate it with a cronjob. Using `crontab -e`, I created this file:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

@reboot cd /home/username/noip-2.1.9-1 && sudo noip2
```

It does not work and I do not know why. It would be nice if somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution: I connected my router to No-IP, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

> cd /home/username/noip-2.1.9-1 && sudo noip2

I would rather execute "sudo crontab -e" to add a cronjob as root (and avoid doing sudo inside the cronjob).

Also I understand you want to execute noip2 (that is inside /home/username/noip-2.1.9-1 folder). So I would change the cronjob as

```
@reboot /home/username/noip-2.1.9-1/noip2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: any output in your system log?

Comment: I don't think so. Is it possible that it does not work because I have to chmod something?

Comment: noip2 should have exec permissions, try with

chmod 755 /home/username/noip-2.1.9-1/noip2

Comment: Does not work either

Comment: Instead of adding it as a cronjob consider to add it as a service
https://gist.github.com/NathanGiesbrecht/da6560f21e55178bcea7fdd9ca2e39b5

Comment: After installing, following the instruction on the [no-ip website](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/install-ip-duc-onto-raspberry-pi/), adding `@reboot /usr/bin/sudo -H /usr/local/bin/noip2` to `crontab -e` works for me on Raspbian 10 (Debian base).